# Is it proper to ask about how Math is applied?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a pretty specific question that I want to ask on Math.SE but I'm unsure if it's the place to do so.

The question I want to ask on Math.SE: How is it that Prime Polynomials are applied to Linear Feedback Shift Registers (LFSR)? I know that exponents in the polynomial indicate taps, but how do they actually *indicate* those taps? What's the connection?

My question here (on meta): Is asking questions about applied mathematics like this acceptable? There is an application of a subject, is this the place to seek an understanding as to how that link works?

Of course it'd be better formed if I actually ask this question, but I mean this as an example.

Comment: Yes, such questions are welcome. Search the main site for questions about LFSRs.

Comment: Anything with primes in it is OK by me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We have the [applications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) exactly for these sort of questions.

Comment: Yay! I'm a regular on StackOverflow, but occasionally I find myself on here on Math. I just want to make sure that I'm asking the proper way in the proper place.